# Cassandra paging: How to page trough entire column family (table) and have part of compound key in resultset

Tags: cassandra, paging

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE someTable (
    user_id uuid,
    id uuid,
    someField string,
    anotherField string,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, id)
);
```

I know that there's a way to do paging in cassandra (https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/paging/)

However, what I need to do is:

- page trough entire table (it's large, so paging is required)
- get all rows of a user_id
- do something with these rows.

In short I need to fetch all the results of 1 user and do this for every record there is. (No, I don't have a unique list of user_ids here)

Also, I know I could do this programatically: paging through all the pages, assume i get it ordered by user_id, and append the last user_id (where rows are cut off) to the next page of results so data of that user gets in the same set.

However, I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

> However, what I need to do is:
>
> page trough entire table (it's large, so paging is required).

Assuming ***you don't know*** the `**user_id**`. And you want to fetch all the users data. To do this use token function to make a range query to get the user_ids.[Displaying rows from an unordered partitioner with the TOKEN function](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useToken.html) something like `select * from someTable where token(a_id) > token(other_id)`;

> get all rows of a user_id

Now you know the user_id and want to fetch all the rows of that user_id. Use range query based on id starting from the MIN_UUID. Like:

`select * from someTable where user_id = 123 and id > MIN_UUID limit 100`

After that query choose the 100th uuid to fetch other rows. such that:

`select * from someTable where user_id = 123 and id > [previous_quries_100th_id(uuid)] limit 100`

Keep querying until you fetched all the rows.

> do something with these rows.

It depends on you what you want to do with all of those rows. Use language specific ResultSet and iterate over rows to do something on there.